# Dealing with Future#get and InterruptedException Sonar java:S2142

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupted-exception

In some legacy code I have inherited, there is a snippet that looks similar to this.

```
List<Callable<String>> callableStrings = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three").stream()
        .map(s -> (Callable<String>) () -> s)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> results =
        someExecutorService.invokeAll(callableStrings).stream()
                .map(
                        future -> {
                            try {
                                return future.get();
                            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                                LOG.info("Unexpected Exception encountered while fetching result", e);
                                return null;
                            }
                        })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Instead of `Callable<String>`, I am really dealing with some heavier computation.  Sonar highlights the `catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e)` as a problem, suggesting that you should always rethrow `InterruptedException`.  https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/multi-threading/RSPEC-2142

The intent of this code seems to be to filter out any of the heavy computations which had a problem, returning only those which succeeded.  For context, this code is called as a result of an HTTP request my application is handling.  If the `InterruptedException` is allowed to propagate all the way to the top then the client is going to get an error response rather than seeing the list of successful results.

There is a lot of different kinds of information to be found on dealing with `InterruptedException` from `Future#get`.  Most of the ones that seem like very clear and solid advice are those that are dealing with a situation where you have implemented something like `Runnable` and are calling `Future#get` from within that class.

This answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4268994, suggests that if I see `InterruptedException` thrown in the code above, that indicates that the thread handling the HTTP request has been interrupted, not the one running the Future.  Is that correct?

My questions are:

- Should I be concerned with the Sonar warning and, if so, what bad things will happen as a result of keeping the code as it is?
- How should the code be refactored to be improved?

Comment: This is code I've inherited.  I am sure Sonar is telling me to do the right thing.  What I am trying to get from the question is to understand more deeply what is going on when that InterruptedException is thrown and how I should respond to it, if at all.

Is it the HTTP request handling thread which was interrupted?  If so, it seems clear that I should just let the exception propagate.

Comment: Since all futures are supposed to be completed when `invokeAll` returns, `InterruptedException` should never occur. Hence, the correct way of handling an exception that should never occur is `catch(InterruptedException ex) { throw new AssertionError(ex); }`

Comment: Thank you @Holger.  That is obviously true.